# Breadcrumbs - vertical or horizontal?

Tags: usability, breadcrumbs

I am planning to keep breadcrumb in my project.

Which one is a good approach: Keeping in vertical or in horizontal form? What are the pros and cons?

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing vertical breadcrumbs. Could you provide an example?

Comment: It often depends on the layout of your website/application. Can you provide us with more details?

Comment: Please provide more details about your application in the question and also if you have any screenshots or mockups it will help with answering the question.

Comment: Vertical breadcrumbs AKA a tree-view.

Comment: @DarrylGodden A tree view shows the entire navigation landscape, while a breadcrumb only shows the trail the user took. These are not just layout variants of each other.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackExchange :)

This realy depends on your application.
Most breadcrumbs on Websites are in horizontal form because that's a nice middle ground from functionallity, completeness and screen space used.

But that doesn't mean it fits your product. What are you trying to achieve? What type of Software is it? You realy have to give us more information in order to get a helpful answer.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I agree horizontal way is quite common, But in my case the application is a banking web app and there will minimum 10 items in the breadcrumbs and the length of the items are bit lengthy.

Comment: A information architecture with a minimum of 10 hierarchy levels sounds like more than most users can handle. Maybe you could group/split that into more usable chunks. But I don't know the details of your app and it might make sense or you're not able to change that.
Anyway, you can collapse the breadcrumb in the middle. Take a look at how atlassian handles this: https://atlaskit.atlassian.com/examples/core/breadcrumbs/many-items

Answer (score 1):

I would argue the more common method would be to go with a horizontal breadcrumb, as this quite easy to see a step by step progression and journey the user has taken to navigate to where they are.

However there are instances where vertical breadcrumbs are advantageous but it does really depend on what it is you are working on.

Comment: Thanks Owen. I agree horizontal way is quite common, But in my case the application is a banking web app and there will minimum 10 items in the breadcrumbs and the length of the items are bit lengthy.

Comment: @RajzeshwarSivaraj it could may well be but it restricts the page layout a lot less, and is fairly clear. If it goes to two lines it maybe a bit much but it does have its advantages.